# Joomla, Make Module Position appear on every page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

Does anyone know how to make a module position appear on every page? I've a position called "bottom" It appears only on some pages, but I would like it to be rendered on every page. Not sure if there's a setting in the Template Config/Layout or something. I can say I am fairly new to Joomla! and most times is a pain to do something outta the box.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: For some of you who're busy down voting a question, what's the point of down voting a question? Don't you understand the definition of the word question!? It means another person doesn't know and they're asking for help! Or is it because you're too genius and you think my question is stupid enough for you? Back to the basics where you were taught how to ask for help when you don't know, doesn't matter if the question seem too simple or stupid enough. Anyway, you should've as well just gone to the next question as simple as that!

If no one understands my anger, I've spent most of the day researching on a solution to this. The first answer below gives me insights. And if you're too genius you should probably read my question again! Not all positions are rendered on every page depending on template and I was simply looking for a solution to make a particular position get rendered on every page without digging into the core files of Joomla!
Anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to first response, there are some module positions that only appear on the website under certain conditions, and these conditions are usually specified in template (mainly in the "index.php" file of the template being used).

Comment: Thanks your comment gave me some direction...I thought though that you could archive this without digging into Joomla's core files, which seems to be the only solutions I come across when I encounter a problem with Joomla!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Got it right, it's simple: `<!-- Bottom --> <?php //if ($this->countModules('bottom') && $hideByView == false): ?> <div id="bottom-row"> <div class="row-container"> <div class="<?php echo $containerClass; ?>"> <div id="bottom" class="<?php echo $rowClass; ?>"> <jdoc:include type="modules" name="bottom" style="themeHtml5" /> </div> </div> </div> </div> <?php //endif; ?>`

Answer (score 1):

It's not the module position you need to assign to every page, but the module itself.

In the Joomla Module Manager, select you module you want to edit, then go to the **Menu Assignment** tab.

You then see the **Module Assignment** option which you need to set to **On All Pages**:

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: I've tried that already. But according to research, a position e.g. "bottom" is not available/rendered on every page depending on template, hence my question. I've assigned my module to to appear on every page, but doesn't show on every page as I explained above.

Comment: @morgs, check the **index.php** file where the position is called and there may possibly be a conditional statement

Comment: thanks for your help. Got it right, it's simple:

`<!-- Bottom -->
      <?php //if ($this->countModules('bottom') && $hideByView == false): ?>
        <div id="bottom-row">
          <div class="row-container">
            <div class="<?php echo $containerClass; ?>">
              <div id="bottom" class="<?php echo $rowClass; ?>">
                <jdoc:include type="modules" name="bottom" style="themeHtml5" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php //endif; ?>`

Comment: `$hideByView` must be true then. You need to figure out where this is coming from

Comment: hi Lodder, as per my comment I just commented out the entire if statement. I only have a 'clients' slider in this position which should appear on every page. So I'm sorted for now unless if another outta the box requirement comes from client then I can worry more.